# C# XML - getting an optional tag?

Tags: c#, xml

I have xml with the following:

```
     <sample intentref="BIZ_hello" count="1">hey</sample>
     <sample intentref="business_status" count="1">status of my order</sample>
     <sample intentref="business_status" count="1">order for my number<annotation conceptref="o_number">12343</annotation>
```

And I'm trying to build a list like this:

| Intent | Sample | Count | Annotation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BIZ_hello | hey | 1 | NONE |
| business_status | status of my order | 1 | NONE |
| business_status | order for my number | 1 | "<annotation conceptref=o_number>12343</annotation>" |

I'm stuck at getting the 'annotated text' part. The code I have so far that works for 'intent' and 'sample' and 'count'...I'm trying to get that optional '' tag .

```cs
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.Load(fileName);

XmlNodeList nodes = xdoc.SelectNodes("project/samples/sample");

foreach (XmlNode xn in nodes)
{

    ParseList tempList = new ParseList();
    tempList.intentName = xn.Attributes["intentref"]?.Value ?? "Unassigned";
    tempList.sampleSentence = xn.FirstChild.Value;
    tempList.countSamples = xn.Attributes["count"].Value;
    tempList.annotatedText = ???

}
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Your XML is not well-formed.

Comment: The XML has an error.  There is not closing angle bracket for last sample element.  Annotation is a child of the last sample.

Comment: `xn.SelectSingleNode("annotation")?.OuterXml`

Comment: @charlieface - Thanks that worked! I'll update the question with more clarity!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following

```cs
tempList.annotatedText = xn["annotation"]?.OuterXml ?? "NONE";
```

The `?` deals with the case when the node is not there. `OuterXml` returns the whole child node as text.